# Why can't I get this 2D array to load properly into my custom CollectionViewCells?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In XCode, I'm writing a program in which data from a 2D String array is loaded into a 140 row by 5 column table. With this sample, if my array were {{a,b,c}{d,e,f}}, I want a table like

```
a  b  c
d  e  f
```

but I keep getting what a, d as the first 2 elements of my table going right on the first row. My code is:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> GridViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GridViewCell{

        var i = 0

        while (i < 5){
        cell.textLabel?.text = wholeArray[indexPath.row][i]

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return cell
        }

    }
    else {
        DLog("ERROR")
        return GridViewCell()
    }
}
```

If there were an indexPath.column, I'd have tried that but there isn't. How might I get this to do what I need? This is a string array; I tried flatten() and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of row, use item with some simple arithmetic:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> GridViewCell {    
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "gridCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? GridViewCell, let columns = wholeArray.first?.count {
        let item = CGFloat(indexPath.item)

        let row = floor(item / CGFloat(columns))
        let column = item.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(columns))

        cell.textLabel?.text = wholeArray[Int(row)][Int(column)]

        return cell
    } // no need to explicitly say else

    print("error")
    return GridViewCell()
```

}

Comment: why is it modulo 3? Also, I tried it to make me cast indexPath.item / 3 into a Double

Comment: @Derry, I changed it from 3 to the number of columns. No more hard coded values :)

Comment: now I'm getting an optional error on the let columns line...this is an array of arrays of string

Comment: @Derry. That is because of the ?. Just move it into the if let line like in my updated answer

Comment: now I get Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFloat'

Comment: @Derry, it's just a matter of moving stuff around ^ (moving the CGFloat cast). I checked and this works now with types and optionals and stuff like that

Comment: this is looking better, but now I get  Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String]]' with an index of type 'CGFloat'

Comment: @Derry, so make sure row and column are Ints.

Comment: @Derry, great happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

var column = position % MAX_ROWS
var row = position / MAX_COLUMNS

This should brake your position (index) down and give you the column and row you can used to index into your 2d array to allow for the result your looking for.

Your basic problem is that the grid is treated like a linear list of cells and you just need some simple math to convert to a 2d grid.